# jstl how to equal string int(ascii)

Tags: java, jstl, equals

In My jsp i want to equal the String and int(assii)

```
<c:foreach var="i" begin="65" end="97" step="1">
      <c:set var="answer1" value="&#${i }"></c:set>
      <%-- it is always false --%>
      <c:if test="${answer1 == 'A' }"> == true</c:if>
      <%-- it is always false --%>
      <c:if test="${answer1 eq 'A' }"> eq true</c:if>

</c:foreach>
```

i had try ,eq,fn:trim,fn:contrines.. ,ne,there are not work

can someone please help me.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi yes,i had try eq,but it is also false

Comment: and what is your expected output?

Comment: @KevalTrivedi ${answer1 } to output it in html===A,B,C....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit lengthy, but it should work:

```
<c:forTokens var="i" delims=","
        items="A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z">
    <c:if test="${i == 'A'}">
    ...
    </c:if>
</c:forTokens>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<c:set var="answer1" value="<%=(char)((int)((Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("i")))%>"></c:set>
```

Comment: sorry,i just want to equal "A","B","C".I can not get you!The 'i' is integer,how to convert it to unicode?

Comment: I edited my answer (yes first one was a mistake, sorry).